# Setting up root directory of nginx in Fedora 19

Tags: linux, nginx, web-server, fedora

So I had nginx set-up with the default site. I decided I wanted to change because my website is at `/var/www/site/`... so before I changed again, I went to `127.0.0.1` to see if everything worked. I did. I got the `This page is hosted by nginx!` OK good. Now I am gonna move root directores to `/var/www/site` because I got an index.html file there.

and then I restart... I get this error:

```
2014/08/07 01:42:35 [error] 24949#0: *1 "/var/www/site/index.html" is forbidden (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1"
```

Comment: I think SELinux is refusing it...

Comment: I don't think I have a  www-data user

Comment: OK, then what are your permissions and SELinux contexts?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a file permission issue. You should be able to see the ownership and permissions with:

`ls -l /var/www/site/index.html`

If you're not familiar with the long output of the `ls` command, checkout the man page (`man ls`) for the details.

You can also quickly test the file permissions theory by *temporarily* opening up permissions. This can be done with:

```
chmod 666 /var/www/site/index.html
```

You'll want to change the permissions to something sensible (based on your specific needs) when you're done.

More details on the `chmod` command can be seen with `man chmod`